# Angular - [innerHTML] doesn't work on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I have a seperate JSON file for translation, it looks like this:

```
  Title: "Welcome to <br> COVID-19 mitigation schemes",
  ...
}
```

In angular when I write

```
<p [innerHTML]="Title"> {{Title}} </p>
```

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE11, it still displays the `<br>` tag.

Any suggestions?

P.S - I need the JSON files for translations. The reason I needed `<br>` was because the text was wrapping at the hyphen on COVID-19. There may be other solutions, but I also need to add `<a>` tags in the middle of the given text.

I could use DomSanitization but ngx-translate does not work properly when I use it in TS file, even when I subscribe to the event. The code for that looks like this

```
this.translateService.get(`Title`).subscribe(data => this.title = data)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You could just write `this.title = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data)`. It has nothing to do with `ngx-translate`. This should just work

Comment: Thanks Bunyamin, I'll try but I noticed ngx-translate does not update the data when language is updated.

Comment: That seems like an another problem but `innerHTML` with `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` should work.

Comment: Haha, yeah fair enough. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this one :

```
 bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text)

  }
```